# cycles light source multiplier factor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, lighting

Hello blender community

In eevee you can change how much a light source interacts withing the scene. For that you have multipliers for Diffuse, Specular and Volume.
It looks like this:

[image]

In cycles, these options don't exist:
[image]

so how could I achieve a similar slider for each light source?

Since I can use nodes for the lights in cycles, maybe there would be a way to do that using nodes?

Any help is appreceated

Comment: Eevee and Cycles don't manage lights the same way, for example what precisely do you get in Eevee that you try to get in Cycles?

Comment: I have a scene with volumetrics. In eevee I have it set so that only one light source can brighten up the volumetrics
but now in cycles all my light sources affect the volumetric, which I don't want